# Adding two polynomials in C, Abort trap: 6

Tags: c

I am trying to add 2 polynomials using int arrays. For example, 
co1[ ] = {5, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, ...} & ex1[ ] = {6, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, ...} represents the polynomial 5x^6 + 3x^2 + 2x. I tried doing this in different ways but I keep getting the message "Abort trap: 6" whenever I try to use this function. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
void add_polynom( int co1[ ], int ex1[ ], int co2[ ], int ex2[ ] )
{
    int tmpC[ASIZE]; //ASIZE = 50
    int tmpE[ASIZE];
    int i, j, k, b, x = 0;

    init_polynom(tmpC, tmpE); //sets all values within tmpC and tmpE to 0

    for(i=0;i<ASIZE;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<ASIZE;j++)
        {
            if(ex1[i] > ex2[j])
            {
                tmpC[x] = co1[i];
                tmpE[x] = ex1[i];
                x++;
            }

            else if(ex1[i] == ex2[j])
            {
                if((ex1[i] == 0) && (ex2[j] == 0))
                {
                    if(k == 0)
                    {
                        tmpC[x] = co1[i] + co2[j];
                        tmpE[x] = 0;
                        x++;
                        k = 1;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        goto jump;
                    }

                }

                else
                {
                    tmpC[x] = co1[i] + co2[j];
                    tmpE[x] = ex1[i];
                    x++;
                }
            }

            else if(ex1[i] < ex2[j])
            {
                tmpC[x] = co2[j];
                tmpE[x] = ex2[j];
                x++;
            }
        }
    }

    jump:
    for(b=0;b<ASIZE;b++)
    {
        co1[b] = tmpC[b];
        ex1[b] = tmpE[b];
    }
}
```

Comment: Posting a [mcve] would help.

Comment: Use a debugger to see which line is causing the trap. And then continue using the debugger to examine program state and execution. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0):

try to give k a value before entering the loop

Comment: I'm afraid that, as stated, this looks more like a comment than an answer. Consider rephrasing it into something like "`k` is not initialized before its use ... and so are `tmpC` and `tempE` ...", but please note that, while an error, this is unlikely what triggered the abort trap.

Comment: tmpC and tempE are initialized before its use in instruction **init_polynom(tmpC, tmpE); //sets all values within tmpC and tmpE to 0 **, next time try to read the code before commenting .

Comment: Fair enough, "read the code" is a good advice. The OP haven't show that function implementation, so we can only hope that their comment and naming are faithful (and probably they are). You seem to have missed the key point of my comment, though.

Comment: i agree with you that it's a comment more than answer, not initializing k couldn't cause this. must be something wrong with the init_polynom (). thank you

Answer (score 0):

In your inner loop you're incrementing `x` beyond `ASIZE` yet you use it to index into arrays you created with a length of `ASIZE`.

Comment: Please, consider mentioning that `x` is incremented beyond `ASIZE` because the OP wrote two *nested* loops to iterate through the source arrays. This should be an O(n) algorithm, a single loop.